# Calling a jsp multiple times from single doPost() method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using PD4ML libraries for converting my .jsp to pdf files and I need to call the same jsp file for a List of values. 
I am doing this in my doPost()

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String [] posSelected = request.getParameterValues("selectPOs");
    for(String eachPO: posSelected){

    request.getRequestDispatcher("CreateInvoices.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

//This does not work as can not create multiple instances of servlet.
    }}

I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed exception.

How can I invoke same JSP multiple times?

Thanks
MekaM

Comment: You are trying to catch a train that has already left the station :) hope you get the idea if not I will elaborate it

Comment: You can send only one response per request in HTTP protocol. You need to try another approach. creating all selected invoices in a single pdf may be one solution.

Comment: @Mudassar. Can you please elaborate. I mean I would like to know how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I invoke same JSP multiple times?*

By including it multiple times.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("CreateInvoices.jsp").include(request, response);
```

Comment: still getting illegal state exception.

Comment: Then it's caused elsewhere.

Comment: But when I debug it is being thrown when i am on this line when my  control enters in the for loop for second time. Basically I just changed forward to include. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Problem is not visible in information provided so far. In other words, when I run exactly the same code as you've posted in the question, supplied with the code in the answer, then I'm not facing the described problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

By using `Include` instead of `Forward` on Request Dispatcher.
You can call same jsp multiple time suing include.

It will look something like this.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("CreateInvoices.jsp").include(request,response);
```

Comment: still getting illegal state exception.

Comment: Copying/repeating other's answers is rude.

Comment: can you paste the new code after implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others you can send only one response per request in HTTP protocol hence you need to try another approach.

In your case since pd4ml is mandatory and here you need multiple pdfs hence creating multiple jsp is not the ideal way. Hence rather than converting the jsp to pdf you should create the multiple pdf through the code as shown in the link
http://pd4ml.com/examples.

```
 private void runConverter(String urlstring, File output) throws IOException {

         if (urlstring.length() > 0) {
                if (!urlstring.startsWith("http://") && !urlstring.startsWith("file:")) {
                              urlstring = "http://" + urlstring;
                }

4               java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(output);

5               if ( proxyHost != null && proxyHost.length() != 0 && proxyPort != 0 ) {
                       System.getProperties().setProperty("proxySet", "true");
                       System.getProperties().setProperty("proxyHost", proxyHost);
                       System.getProperties().setProperty("proxyPort", "" + proxyPort);
                }

6               PD4ML pd4ml = new PD4ML();

7               try {                                                              
                       pd4ml.setPageSize( landscapeValue ? pd4ml.changePageOrientation( format ): format );
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                if ( unitsValue.equals("mm") ) {
                       pd4ml.setPageInsetsMM( new Insets(topValue, leftValue,
bottomValue, rightValue) );
                } else {
                       pd4ml.setPageInsets( new Insets(topValue, leftValue,
bottomValue, rightValue) );
                }

                pd4ml.setHtmlWidth( userSpaceWidth );

8               pd4ml.render( urlstring, fos );
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used jsoup.connect().get() to achieve what I wanted.